# Event.target.id returns HTML id value or HTML name value?

Tags: javascript, php, html, events, target

HTML:

```
<form id="form-product-add" style="display: inline;">
  <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="<?= $this->csrf; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="add" value="true">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Agregar Producto" class="btn btn-default hidden-lg">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
forms.forEach(form => {
        form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const formData = new FormData(form);
            const url = window.location.href;
            const thisForm = event.target;
            const formId = event.target.id;
 
            switch (formId) {
              case 'form-register':
                 code...
              break;

              case 'form-product-add':
                 code...
              break;
            }
       }
}
```

**My Question:**
`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="">` avoids the script not enter to the switch. When I comment this line, the switch works fine.
Check, I uses **id** attribute in HTML form and the name of one Hidden field is **id**

Event.target.id refers to HTML's id or name?

Comment: This is a "specialty" of the form element, that named form fields can be accessed using the `form.fieldname` syntax. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement#accessing_the_forms_elements has more on that.

Answer (score 0):

when you have

> `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="">`

in your code, then const formId gets assigned to it.

and when u remove it then it works completely fine.

try console.log(formId) for both the cases you will see the difference.
the reason is since you make name="id" somehow target.id becomes the element with name="id"